# Problem showing first image of product gallery as product image on category page

Tags: php, woocommerce

I use the action below to show the first image of the product gallery instead of the normal product image.
I now want the action to only work on a certain category page but when I uncomment the lines below it doesn't work.
What is wrong with my code?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'bs_replace_loop_product_thumbnail' );

function bs_replace_loop_product_thumbnail() {
    
//    if( is_product_category('dames') ) {
    
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
    
    function bs_replace_product_thumbnail() {
        global $product;
        $attachment_id = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids()[0];
        echo "<img src='" . wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ) . "'>";
    }
    
//}
    
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'bs_replace_product_thumbnail', 10 );
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further inspection I noticed the `if` statement was not covering all the necessary code. Below is a working answer.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'bs_replace_loop_product_thumbnail' );

function bs_replace_loop_product_thumbnail() {
    
    if ( is_product_category('dames') ) {

    function bs_replace_product_thumbnail() {
        global $product;
        $attachment_id = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids()[0];
        echo "<img src='" . wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ) . "'>";
    }
    
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'bs_replace_product_thumbnail', 10 );
        
    }
    
}
```